# Object doesn't support this property or method for adding in formula

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I have the following code that keeps throwing an error:

Object doesn't support this property or method

```
expectedProjectWS.Range("A" & lastAddress + 1).Offset(1, 3).Formula "=SUM(D11:(OFFSET(" & newrow & ",-1,0)))"
```

I am trying to add in a formula after the row is pasted in. I have debug printed this and it works prints correctly which is confusing.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Providing `expectedProjectWS` is a valid reference to a worksheet, `lastAddress` is a row number and `newrow` is a cell reference as a string then you've just forgotten to put the `=` after the word formula.

This will place the formula `=SUM(D11:(OFFSET(D18,-1,0)))` in cell `D7`.

```
Sub test()

    Dim expectedProjectWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastAddress As Long
    Dim newrow As String

    Set expectedProjectWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastAddress = 5
    newrow = "D18"

    expectedProjectWS.Range("A" & lastAddress + 1).Offset(1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(D11:(OFFSET(" & newrow & ",-1,0)))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just out of interest - would it not be the Offset not containing the formula function? this is exactly how i have this setup and i still get the error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - _would it not be the Offset not containing the formula function_